# how to commute two buttons

Tags: java, button, radio-button

When I want commute 2 TextView A and B, I do:

```
string temp = tvA.getText().toString();
tvA.setText(tvB.getText().toString());
tvB.setText(temp);
```

So if I want commute 2 button, how?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Swap the labels on the buttons?  What language are you using?

Comment: I'm using Java in eclipse. I want when I click button Change, button A become button B and button B become button A. Help me, please.

Comment: I'm still not sure what exactly you want to do.  Do you want to exchange the text on buttons or move buttons around and swap locations?  Are you using awt, Swing or something else?

Comment: Define the term "commute" in this context, please.

Comment: OK. I want move two buttons together, commute them

Answer (score 1):

Commute is a correct term, but it makes what you are trying to achieve sound more difficult than it really is...

The whole idea, as is evident from your code, is about swapping labels. You must add an ActionListener to every button:

```
    jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
```

And then have each ActionListener call `commute();`

There is no need to use `toString()` since `getText()` returns a String already.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    commute();
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    commute();
}                                        

private void commute() {
    String temp = jButton1.getText();
    jButton1.setText(jButton2.getText());
    jButton2.setText(temp);
}
```